# Force initial zoom in HTML or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

I have an HTML/Bootstrap/JavaScript project that seems to scale in such a way that it looks best at 125%.

Is there a way to force the browser to start at 125%? I've tried

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.25"/>`

But that did not seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually, it appears to possibly work in IE, but not in Chrome. What I'm really after is a browser-independent method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend giving your page an initial zoom.  It is an unnecessary hack that could look different across browsers, but even if it looked the same, why not use CSS and HTML to give the page the look you want?   Zoom is an accessibility feature for users and shouldn't be controlled by the site itself.  You could just rewrite the CSS so that it has the same look as the 125% zoom.

And to reiterate, cross browser issues are also a problem, which is another reason to just use CSS/HTML to get the effect you want.

Comment: Yes, that would be preferable. I'll look into resizing my elements, but I am pretty novice. :)

Comment: Understandable.  When you run into problems just ask away!  That's what we're here for!  And it'll be a good learning experience to go through the pains of reworking your CSS :)

Comment: If anyone sees this in the future and is considering going ahead with a zoomed approach, know that it WILL cause cross-browser problems (**especially** in Firefox), and it usually isn't too difficult to rework your CSS (especially in Bootstrap). @John Harding was spot on, you'll be much happier maintaining it if you rework your CSS.